# jstl выбор локали

Tags: java, java-ee

Проблема с выбором языка в тегах jstl.
В сервлете я определяю выбранную локаль(Она меняется по нажатому на страничке флажку), добавляю в качестве атрибута к сессии объект Locale и передаю в jsp. Как в jsp странице эту информацию извлечь и применить к тегу? У меня есть класс, из который локализует страницу и в зав от  выдает мне значение ключа, но не понимаю как это сделать динамически в зависимости от того, какая локаль была выбрана и установлена сервлетом. Пытался так:

```
<fmt:setLocale value="<%=request.getSession().getAttribute("locale").toString()%>"/>
```

не получается, гугл не помог, какое решение?

Comment: А как вы сервлету отправляете информацию?

Comment: спасибо, но задачу уже решил, можно было считать атрибуты через jstal tags

Comment: В таком случае, опубликуйте, пожалуйста, ответ. Это может быть полезным для будущих посетителей. :)